# React-router-dom and nested routes on an IIS server

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router-dom

Good day everyone!

Quick rundown:

We have a React app running on IIS, with some routes, naturally. Currently the setup works perfectly as we want, except for nested routes. I checked with our web server IT guy and his config seems to be correct based on the articles I found regarding this.

For SEO purposes we want to use nested routes, e.g. promotions/some-cool-promo, now we have a promotions page, but links to the other promos from there.

Whenever a nested route is used, I get the following error in the browser. Honestly I have no idea why this is happening, as I've been doing this for 2 years now, and in the past projects I've worked on the routing was already set up, and none of them use nested routes. Side note, this works when running the project locally.

What I'm using:

React-router-dom v6.22.2

Router setup example is below. And the router const is then passed as a prop to the RouterProvider in App.jsx

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter(

    [

        {

            path: '/',

            element: <Home />

        },

        {

            path: '/featured-promotions',

            element: <Promos />,

            children: [

                { path: 'some-cool-promo', element: <LazySomeCoolPromo /> },

                { path: 'spin-spin-spin', element: <LazySpinSpinSpin /> },

            ]

        },

    ]

);
```

Can anyone help, please?

[The error I get in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK8c2.png)

I was expecting the nested routes to just work, same as all of the other routes.